# i have 3 lan ports in my motherboard.how to disable all the onboard LAN port on linux machine?

Tags: linux

i am building custom operating system with motherboard(MSI Gaming motherboard) and two e1000e driver support NIC cards.i want to use ports which is in nic card instead of onboard.

for disabling onboard port,i tried with 70-persistance-rule.but it didn't worked for me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This would appear to be off-topic, as it is not a programming question. ServerFault might be a better place, but perhaps not, Having said that, you may be able to disable in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to determine what the driver is. To do this, open a terminal and run the command:

```
    lshw -C network|more
```

This will display a load of information about your network device/s. Somewhere in the output you will see module=drivername in my case the Intel onboard NIC driver was module=e1000e

Once you have identified the driver name open /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

At the bottom of the file add the following line (this uses my driver module (e1000e) as an example, just replace it with the module name of yours)

```
  blacklist e1000e
```

Reboot for the blacklist to take effect. From now on whenever Linux boots, the kernel will not load the driver for the NIC.